# How to check if json is empty or not?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var km = localStorage.getItem("prefereddistance");
    var minPrice = localStorage.getItem("minprice");
    var maxPrice = localStorage.getItem("maximumprice");
    var requestUrl = serverUrl + "?api=" + apiVersion + "&user_login_token=" + authUser.user_login_token + "&getuserproduct1";
    console.log(requestUrl);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            ++relog;
            document.getElementById("displaycard").style.visibility = "hidden";
            var dataJson = xhr.responseText;
```

Is dataJson empty or not, here?

I want to check this.

Comment: `!!dataJson && Object.keys(dataJson).length`

Comment: I'd guess you first need to parse `responseText`:
`var dataJson = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)` then check if it has any entry:
`console.log(Object.keys(x).length > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

you can check if it has any keys:

```
Object.keys(dataJson).length
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if the `responseText` is an empty string:

```
dataJson === '' // true if no JSON data (it's an empty string)
```

To check if there is it is an empty object:

```
dataJson === '{}' // true if empty
```

You may also want to check if it is an empty array, depending on your use case:

```
dataJson === '[]' // true if empty
```

To check if the parsed object is empty:

```
const data = JSON.parse(dataJson);
!!Object.keys(data).length // false if empty
```

Comment: thanks for your help. But I have a request.dataJson is empty but !!Object.keys(data).length always return true.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with this `!!dataJson && Object.keys(dataJson).length`

```js
function check(dataJson) {
  return !!dataJson && Object.keys(dataJson).length;
}

console.log(check(""));
console.log(check([]));
console.log(check({}));
console.log(check({"name" :"test"}));
```